# Python Serial Writes to Arduino is different from Arduino's Serial Monitor's Serial Writes

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I have a Python script that writes a string `test` to the Arduino serial port. If the arduino receives the `test` string, it should reply with a string `ok` and LED 13 should like up..

**Problem:** When the Arduino Serial Monitor is used to write `test` to serial port, Arduino replies with `ok` as expected and the LED #13 lights up.

However when the Python script writes `test` to the same serial port, nothing happens. Arduino does not reply to serial port and the LED #13 does not light up.

Any ideas how Python script can be fixed to get the `ok` response from Arduino and LED 13 to light up?

**Arduino Sketch**

```
int ledPin = 13;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {

    while(Serial.available() == 0) { }
    
    if(Serial.readString() == "test\r\n") {
      Serial.print("ok\r\n");
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    } 
    
    readString = ""; // Clear recieved buffer
    delay(100);
}
```

**Python Script**

```
port = 'COM5'
ser = serial.Serial(
    port=port,
    baudrate=9600,
    timeout=5
)

serial.write("test\r\n")

response = serial.readline()
print response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
port = 'COM5'
ser = serial.Serial(
    port=port,
    baudrate=9600,
    timeout=5
)

# you need to sleep after opening the port for a few seconds
time.sleep(5) # arduino takes a few seconds to be ready ...

#also you should write to your instance
ser.write("test\r\n")
# and give arduino time to respond
time.sleep(0.5)
response = self.serial.readline()
print response
```

if you dont want to wait a fixed number of seconds you probably need to wait for `ser.cts` (clear to send)

Comment: Works!! Spent over an hour trying encoding of string and stuff lol

Comment: I have had lottttts of experience with python + serial + ardiuno ;P

Comment: Awesome! A related question: In an infinite loop in Python, it takes about a second for Arduino to reply with `ok` after sending `test`. Is there a way to speed this up?